# How to open a new sub tab and then change focus to it in Service Cloud?

Tags: javascript, service-cloud-console, console

I am able to open my sub-tab but I am struggling to change the browsers focus to it for the user. The tab is opening correctly.  Can you advise how I can get the ID of the new tab and then change focus to it?

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:commandButton value="Book {!theDateToday}"  reRender="hidden" onclick="openRecord();setFocusSubTab(); " >
```

**Javascript (within the same page)**

```
    function openOrder(){
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
    }
    var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result) {
        var primaryTabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'https://wwww.testurl.com', false, 
            'New Record', null, openSuccess, 'newRecordTab');
    };
    var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
        //Report whether we succeeded in opening the subtab
        if (result.success == true) {
            //alert('subtab successfully opened');
        } else {
            //alert('subtab cannot be opened');
        }
    };


    function setFocusSubTab(){
        sforce.console.getSubtabIds(focusSubTab);
    }

    var focusSubTab = function focusSubTab(result){
        sforce.console.focusSubtabById(result);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lesson: Always read the documentation!

This line was wrong:

```
 sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'https://wwww.testurl.com', false, 
        'New Record', null, openSuccess, 'newRecordTab');
```

The second parameter determines if the subtab is displayed immediately.

```
     sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId , 'https://wwww.testurl.com', true, 
        'New Record', null, openSuccess, 'newRecordTab');
```

By amending the second attribute (called the active attribute) I can display the subtab immediately.  As per the documentation: if true, the opened subtab displays immediately. If false, the opened subtab displays in the background and the current tab maintains focus.

[Click here for the documentation.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_opensubtab.htm)

Comment: Kindly update your answer, it is not clear.